# how to avoid repeating same words in one sentence

Tags: phrase-request, ellipsis

I have one sentence which should explain two different things. These two things have the same works. I would like to express the idea without repeating the words.

> Model A is established in order to uncover complex dependency structures in the high-dimension data. It can facilitate the comprehensive study of the complex dependency structure in high-dimensional data.

How can I avoid repeating words?

Comment: **"Model A is established in order to uncover complex dependency structures in the high-dimension data, *and also to facilitate the comprehensive study of the same."*** The preposition 'to' along with separator 'and' would refer it back to the 'same' thing i.e. the complex dependency structure in high-dimensional data.

Comment: @MaulikV Thank you so much. Do you think **"Model A is established in order to uncover complex dependency structures in the high-dimension data, which then can facilitate the comprehensive study of the same."** is good?

Comment: Yes, no problem at least to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in technical writing, clarity is more important than style. If the repetition makes the text clearer, consider keeping it.

That being said, it's easier to avoid repeating the subject of a sentence.

This attempt didn't actually work (data isn't actually the subject of the first sentence, and the sentences are not clear), but hopefully it should give you an idea to work with:

Our research addresses complex dependency structures in high-dimension data, which Model A is established in order to uncover and facilitate the comprehensive study of.

(EDIT: So, ok: 
Model A is established in order to uncover, and facilitate the comprehensive study of, complex dependency structures in the high-dimension data.)